# Strange numbers in SocketIo events data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to learn SocketIo in NodeJS. I'm using .on and .emit functions with same event name but server dont see incoming event emitted by client but client recive some strange numbers as data to event.

I was trying to change .on to .addListener but this is still not working.

Server:

```
const io = require('socket.io');
const server = io.listen(8089);

server.on('connect', socket => {
  console.log('New connection!') // this line is working fine!
  socket.on('ping', incomingMessage => {
    console.log('Incoming message!');
    socket.emit('pong', incomingMessage);
  });
});
```

Client code:
Im using cdn from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js

```
const server = io('http://127.0.0.1:8089');
server.on('connect', () => {
  server.on('pong', message => {
    console.log('Incoming message! ', message);
  });
  server.emit('ping', 'test message');
})
```

But i dont see 'Incoming message' in server side terminal. Client sucessfully connected to server socket and after ~ 5 seconds i recive strange messages like: 
  - Incoming message! 1
  - Incoming message! 3
  - Incoming message! 4
in webbrowser console (using Opera)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i fixed this issue :v the problem was ping-pong event names that already was used by socket.io if i changed event names everything is working fine.